# Create a matrix of available pairings in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `games` that looks like this:

```
             P1         P2
1      Johannes       Paul
2      Johannes       Falk
3          Paul       Falk
4          Paul        Kai
.           ...        ...
```

...and so on, where every row matches a game of the two players.
Now I want to have a table or matrix that shows the games that already took place, somewhat like this:

```
          Johannes  Paul  Falk    Kai
Johannes     FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
Paul          TRUE FALSE  TRUE   TRUE
Falk          TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE
Kai          FALSE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE
```

The best I came up with was `table(games$P1.Spieler, games$P2.Spieler)`, which doesn't quite do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `melt` the dataset to 'long' format, `transform` the 'value' to `factor` with `levels` specified, get the `table` and do the `crossprod`.  Then, we double negate to convert the 0 to FALSE and all other values to TRUE.

```
library(reshape2)
!!crossprod(table(transform(melt(as.matrix(games))[-2], 
            value = factor(value, levels= unique(value)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the  `igraph` package:

Load the data.frame into an undirected igraph

```
library(igraph)
g <- as.undirected(graph.data.frame(df))
```

Get the adjacency matrix with a simple function call:

```
> get.adjacency(g, sparse = F)
         Johannes Paul Falk Kai
Johannes        0    1    1   0
Paul            1    0    1   1
Falk            1    1    0   0
Kai             0    1    0   0
```

You can even plot it:

[image: Plot of network]