# How to create a cross reference table in R?

Tags: r, cross-reference

I am trying to make a cross reference table from a dataset in long format with IDs that have registered preferences of flower species. The cross reference table should list all the flower vertically and horizontally and for each flower show the frequency of likes of other flowers based upon the dataset.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ID=rep(1:5, c(3,3,2,1,4)),
  Flower=c("Azalea","Begonia","Buttercup","Rose","Sunflower")[
    c(4,2,5,2,1,3,4,3,1,5,4,3,2)
  ]
)

#   ID    Flower
#1   1      Rose
#2   1   Begonia
#3   1 Sunflower
#4   2   Begonia
#5   2    Azalea
#6   2 Buttercup
#7   3      Rose
#8   3 Buttercup
#9   4    Azalea
#10  5 Sunflower
#11  5      Rose
#12  5 Buttercup
#13  5   Begonia
```

Intended output:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a simple dataset and desired output to ilustrate your problem?

Comment: Thanks for responding to the request for the data, but the image is not very helpful.  We would have to type it all in again. Instead,  please use the function `dput` to create a text version that we can just cut and paste.

Comment: @G5W - I did the edit on behalf of OP - the intended output is the only part that is an image now. That should be sufficient to answer the question easily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111717/create-a-matrix-of-available-pairings-in-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

One straight forward solution is to use `crossprod()/tcrossprod()` with `table()`:

```
crossprod(table(dat))

#           Flower
#Flower      Azalea Begonia Buttercup Rose Sunflower
#  Azalea         2       1         1    0         0
#  Begonia        1       3         2    2         2
#  Buttercup      1       2         3    2         1
#  Rose           0       2         2    3         2
#  Sunflower      0       2         1    2         2
```

Comment: Well ain't that something. I'm glad I didn't post my embarrassingly complicated answer now.

Comment: I've never seen @thelatemail stumped, my world is crashing :{

Comment: @rawr - if you sat behind me at work you'd see me stumped on an hourly basis. Believe me, i'm just another hack :-)

Comment: @thelatemail It's a nice trick I learned from SO, not as often used though. :)